# node.js fixed line text

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to create a simple CLI-based UI in Node.js. For example:

example:

```
process1: on hold
process2: 1m 23sec
process3: 5m 13sec
process4: on hold
```

I want these lines to have a fixed display position since console logging can look messy. Is there a solution to achieve this without relying on heavy 3rd-party libraries? My current script is only 30 lines long, including logs, and I don't want to make it significantly heavier.

Perhaps something like:

```
console.write('text', [line number]);
```

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. Can you be more specific? Are you trying to format `console.log` output in node to align things in columns?

Comment: Without doing some significant mucking around with third party libraries, this will take a lot of work to do. I'd recommend something like https://github.com/sindresorhus/ansi-escapes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of modules if you search on npms.io for things like `ansi`.

Here is one way to do it.

```
      import clc from 'cli-color';

      process.stdout.write(clc.erase.screen);
      process.stdout.write(clc.erase.line);
      process.stdout.write(clc.move.to(0,0));
      process.stdout.write('status: ok');
      // .. other stuff happens for awhile
      process.stdout.write(clc.erase.line);
      process.stdout.write(clc.move.to(0,0));
      process.stdout.write('status: issue');
```